# Jekkisch Käppchen (kaepchen)

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, kippa-yarmulka, yekke

Is there anyplace on the internet where one could purchase a Jekkische kippah (or käppchen, in German)? I would be looking preferably for ones made out of non-synthetic fabric if possible.

Comment: What do they look like, and what are they made of? Some of the photos from this Yekkish shul feature some distinctive headgear, an unusual type of hat -- is that what you mean? http://www.kajinc.org/photo-gallery If so, I would contact the shul.

Comment: @Kordovero, All of my attempts to contact KAJ have failed, although the kippot look somewhat like that; I'll upload a photo.

Comment: Have you managed to find one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact K'hal Adath Jeshurun in Washington heights ([KAJinc.org](http://kajinc.org)) for the contact info of the individuals who make them.

Answer (score 2):

The address for buying a white kaepchen in EY is:

דינר, שמשון רפאל. נתיבות המשפט 44, מודיעין עילית 7182822
Telephone number 08-9742786

Comment: Does the contact mind having his name and address and phone number posted here?